# Laravel has an exists modifier in the form validator?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
$validator = Validator::make($post,
    array(

        'f_name' => 'required|min:7',
        'l_name' => 'required|min:7',
        'login' => 'required|unique:users|min:7'
    )
);
```

is there something to check if the record exists?

something like this:

```
'login' => 'required|min:|exists:users'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is `exists:table,column`. Example:

```
$validator = Validator::make($post, array(
    'f_name' => 'required|min:7',
    'l_name' => 'required|min:7',
    'login'  => 'required|min:7|exists:users,login'
));
```

More on docs: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-exists